# python kafka: how to make each msg consumed only once by group from begining

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am using [Kafka consumer](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html) here (version 1.3.1).

What I am going to acheive:

- There are 10 partitions. each partition begins with offset 0.
- There is a group of consumers (1,2,3, eg).
- Sometimes, one consumer is down or is up.
- So, the group members may change. But I want each message in each partition should be consumed by the group only once (1 OR 2 OR 3).

My codes are:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my_topic',
            bootstrap_servers=['ip:9092'],
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
            max_partition_fetch_bytes=131072,
            group_id='writer.test')
```

Is the above configuration enough? Any comments welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

**I tried the following codes. Each time in partition 760, each message maybe consumed twice by two consumers in one group. Why? Something wrong?**

```
def test():
    #PULL FROM KAFKA
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            'topic',
            bootstrap_servers=[ip],
            auto_offset_reset='latest',
            max_partition_fetch_bytes=131072,
            auto_commit_interval_ms=500,
            group_id='writer2.test')

    print consumer.poll()
    for i in range(10000):
        msg = next(consumer)
        if str(msg[1])=='670':
            print 'partition= %s, offset= %s' % (msg[1], msg[2])
    consumer.unsubscribe()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        test()
```

Output 1:

```
{}
partition= 670, offset= 224
partition= 670, offset= 225
partition= 670, offset= 226
partition= 670, offset= 227
partition= 670, offset= 228
partition= 670, offset= 229
partition= 670, offset= 230
partition= 670, offset= 231
partition= 670, offset= 232
partition= 670, offset= 233
partition= 670, offset= 234
partition= 670, offset= 235
partition= 670, offset= 236
partition= 670, offset= 237
partition= 670, offset= 238
partition= 670, offset= 239
partition= 670, offset= 240
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
```

Run the same file in another window, output:

```
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
{}
partition= 670, offset= 241
partition= 670, offset= 242
partition= 670, offset= 243
partition= 670, offset= 244
partition= 670, offset= 245
partition= 670, offset= 246
partition= 670, offset= 247
partition= 670, offset= 248
partition= 670, offset= 249
partition= 670, offset= 250
partition= 670, offset= 251
partition= 670, offset= 252
partition= 670, offset= 253
partition= 670, offset= 254
partition= 670, offset= 255
partition= 670, offset= 256
partition= 670, offset= 257
partition= 670, offset= 258
partition= 670, offset= 259
```

Comment: Are you using single broker or multiple brokers cluster?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri multiple broker cluster. Any difference?

Comment: I believe your problem is, you are having multiple consumers. And the data which you are broadcasting is been received by all the consumers. But you want it to be consumed by just one consumer. Am I correct?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri see my update. Thanks

Comment: Earlier I have worked on it. The issue which we faced was earlier versions of Kafka maintain the commit status (i.e consumption of offset) at consumer side. And the library do not provide any way to communicate between consumers. However in the new version of Kafka (I guess Kafka 2.1 or +, not sure of the version), it is maintained at the broker and hence it is not needed to be handled. Just verify it once, and rest is fine with you.

Comment: Do not forget to set the offset expire value on your brokers i.e time for which the data will remain in the Kafka  queue which is by default of 7 days, is too much load on the memory

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I tried but it did not work as my expect ion. so I posted the question.

Comment: Would you explain a bit regarding which part is not expected? You haven't mentioned that information :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use consumer groups, Kafka provides at-least-once delivery guarantees, thus, on failure of a consumer an re-assignment of those consumer's partitions some messages might be delivered a second time.

If you want to make sure, no message is processed twice, you can switch your pattern to at-most-once delivery guarantees. However, for this, you might loose some messages (ie, never processed) in case of failure.

To enable at-most-once, you need to disable auto-commit, and commit manually directy after `poll`, ie, before you start processing the messages received via `poll`.

See http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html#detailed-examples for more details (even if the examples are not in Python, the general pattern is the same).